# Make a div slide out from button on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently learning some jQuery, and I've created a button that when clicked, toggles this div containing colored buttons:

[image]

When these colored buttons are pressed, the main (white button) changes color according to the color pressed. However, is there a way I can have this div of colored buttons slide out from the button div (say, to the right), on mouse hover where they can be selected?

here's the jQuery I have so far:

```
//When clicking diff colours
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $('button').removeClass().addClass(this.className);
});

//When white button is pressed
$("#revealColorSelect").click(function(){
  //Show color select or hide the color select
  changeColor();
  $("#colorSelect").toggle();
});

//update the new colour
function changeColor() {
  var p = $("#pink").val();
  var pur = $("#purple").val();
  var r = $("#red").val();
  var b = $("#blue").val();
  var g = $("#green").val();
  var o = $("#orange").val();
};
```

Comment: could you provide  a fiddle with the current code ? would like to see the html as well

Comment: html and css here:

https://jsfiddle.net/1osb83fk/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [toggle](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/) function like  this. Please rememeber that you will have to add Jquery ui for this.

```
$("#revealColorSelect").on("mouseover",function() {
  //Show color select or hide the color select
  $('#colorSelect').toggle('slide', {
    direction: 'right'
  }, 500, function() {
    changeColor();
  })    
});
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2o61gyyr/

Comment: Really appreciate the help @Deep

Comment: @theking Glad to help :)